# Table and Body with two separate background colors

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Hey all, simple question I'm sure, but I would like to have the body of a page be one color and to have the table in the center a separate color. I tried specifying body color and table color, but body always overrides it. I'm attempting this in css, and I have a feeling I need to use a "not" excluder to make this happen? Such as specifying body not:table or something along the lines of that. Absolute beginner here, so be easy on me. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of what you currently have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your styles are actually being applied to your `table` tag. If your `table` does not change colors, then your CSS selector is likely wrong.

Here is a simple example of styles being applied to the `body` tag. The class `bg` is added to the `table` tag in the markup, so it will pick up the other colors. 
See here: http://jsfiddle.net/uEgrg/

Answer (score 1):

If you *literally* tried to apply `body color` and `table color` that'd be invalid. Both for (x)html *and* css.

`color` addresses the foreground (text) colour of an element, whereas `background-color` addresses its, well, background-colour. So:

```
body {background-color: #ffa; }
/* sets the background of the `body` element to #ffa (yellow) */

table {background-color: #f90; }
/* sets the background of the `table` element to #f90 (orange) */
```

I wouldn't suggest you ever *use* these colours together, but they're highly visible and leave no mistake about whether they're being applied, or not.

Most properties in css cascade down, some do not. But `table {/* css */}` is enough to cause the new values to override those set for a parent/ancestor element. Providing the new values are explicitly stated.

Apparently while there *is* a [CSS3 `not()` selector](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/) (I had thought it was just a jQuery implementation, wow...), it would seem that it's implemented only in 'modern' browsers, so not widely useful at the moment. And it wouldn't really address your situation.